# Использование INDEX FAST FULL SCAN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, оптимизация-запросов

Почему в этом запросе используется INDEX RANGE SCAN, а не INDEX FAST FULL SCAN ведь все значения есть в самом к индексе и их можно выбрать оттуда, не обращаясь к таблице?

```
-- Создание таблицы и построение функционального индекса
create table del_nvl_ind as
select 
    id,
    case when val < 1 then null else round(val)*12 end val
from
(
    select 
        level id, 
        level * dbms_random.value val
    from dual 
    connect by level < 1000000
);

create index del_nvl_idx_nvl on del_nvl_ind (nvl(val,0));

-- Получение плана запроса
explain plan for
select val from del_nvl_ind where nvl(val,0) = 100;    
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

| Id  | Operation                           | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                 | 10000 |   107K|   600   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| DEL_NVL_IND     | 10000 |   107K|   600   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | DEL_NVL_IDX_NVL |  4000 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(NVL("VAL",0)=100)
```

И еще вопрос - как можно изменить запрос, чтобы в плане появился INDEX FAST FULL SCAN?

Comment: *ведь все значения есть в самом к индексе* Нет. Значение `val` в индексе отсутствует. Вот было бы `select nvl(val,0) from del_nvl_ind where nvl(val,0) = 100; ` - тогда индекс и правда был бы покрывающий.

Comment: Понял. Запрос select nvl(val,0) from del_nvl_ind where nvl(val,0) = 100 действительно убирает из плана обращение к таблице по rowid, но последняя строка все равно INDEX RANGE SCAN. А почему не используется INDEX FAST FULL SCAN? Я предполагал, что именно этот метод доступа и будет использован при выборе из индекса.

Comment: И index_ffs вы вряд ли получите на таком запросе. Потому что не даром там слово FULL - это полное сканирование индекса, которое медленнее RANGE SCAN. Этот метод применяется только когда искать по самому индексу не представляется возможным (колонки например не в том порядке, который можно использовать или по другим причинам требуется множественная выборка из разных регионов), но данных в индексе достаточно, что бы не обращаться к таблице, размер которой больше индекса (в ней больше разных колонок)

Comment: `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` прочитает вам весь индекс. Но зачем вам это. У вас `1 000 000`, а под условия индекса попадет допустим 100. Прочитать только нужные блоки в индексе будет быстрее

Comment: Зачем сканировать **весь** индекс, когда разумнее искать значения от 100 до 100. Т.е. искать верхнюю и нижнюю границы записей с указанным значением.

Comment: Коллеги, спасибо. Не до конца понимал различия между этими методами. С вашей помощью стало намного яснее.

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст оформите все это ответом. Может кому то еще пригодится )

Comment: @Viktorov: Добавил, поправьте, если что-то неверно

Comment: Не совсем по теме вопроса, а зачем вы в индексе использовали `nvl(val,0)`, что вы хотели этим добится?

Comment: @0xdb: Дело в том, что операции, подобные NVL, SUBSTR и некоторые другие блокируют использование индекса. Выход - построение функционального индекса. Поэтому он и был создан для индексации null - значений и оптимизации времени и способа выборки.

Comment: Это понятно, но какой смысл в этом выражении `where nvl(val,0) = 100`? Или у вас другая задача и оно просто сюда случайно попало? Для индексации null значений NVL уже давно не используется.

Comment: @0xdb: Я на NVL просто рассматривал пример построения функционального индекса и его влияние на план запроса. Чисто теоретическое построение, без задачи. А что используется для индексации null? Coalesce, case when... ? Просветите, пожалуйста, на будущее.

Comment: Ааа, тогда понятно. Для индексации null надо просто константу вставить - `create index del_nvl_idx_nvl on del_nvl_ind (val, 1)`, тогда нет нужды nvl() в листе запрооса.

Comment: @0xdb: Спасибо, не знал о такой возможности

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обращение к таблице и использование INDEX RANGE SCAN присутствовало ввиду следующих причин:

1. Индекс построенный на nvl(val,0) не был покрывающим для поля val. Так как в индексе содержались уже преобразованные значения, а в самой таблице исходные (без преобразования функцией). После изменения в разделе SELECT запроса выражения VAL на NVL(VAL,0) индекс был использован уже без обращения к таблице с исходными данными.
2. INDEX RANGE SCAN - это метод доступ а к диапазону данных индекса, а INDEX (FAST) FULL SCAN - метод доступа к полному набору данных. А так как в предикате запроса (WHERE) содержалось условие, ограничивающее набор данных, то полная выборка не имела смысла, поэтому и был использован именно этот метод доступа (RANGE SCAN).